# ingress redirect to unexpected path

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I am new to ingress and trying to set up ingress for Prometheus. But I am facing a redirect error about it.

Symptom:
Here is my ingress configuration file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-service
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /prometheus/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

When I am trying to access Prometheus through "http://localhost/prometheus". the URL will automatically redirect to "http://localhost/graph", but the accessible URL should be "http://localhost/prometheus/graph", so How do configure ingress so that it could be redirected to "http://localhost/prometheus/graph" automatically when I just type "http://localhost/prometheus"?